# A colimit in a subcategory

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, functors, diagram-chasing

I do not understand [here](http://www.math.muni.cz/%7Erosicky/papers/neum.ps) what do the words **colimit of a filtered diagram in $\cal P$,not just in $\cal F$**  on the 2nd page mean, namely the word **just** there; is some direction trivial ?
Namely,in general if one has categories $\cal K\subseteq L$ and a scheme $F:\cal D\to K$ then is it always the case that the colimit
in $\cal K$ is  a colimit in $\cal L$ or vice versa ? I cannot calculate this as in $\cal L$ we have more commutative co-cones and also
morphisms from the colimit cocone so we may violate both the uniqueness and existence of
the colimit induced morphism in $\cal K$: $\operatorname{colim} F$.

BTW, what is bigger $\cal P$ or $\cal F$ in that paper cited ?
My guess is $$\cal P\subseteq F.$$

For those who cannot open the file the two relevant pages:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know if I'm the only one, but I can't open the file. Also, if I understand correctly, you've already answered your answer. Something that is a colimit in a subcategory $\mathcal A$ of a category $\mathcal B$, may not be a colimit in $\mathcal B$, so if you have a colimit in $\mathcal A$, then *a priori* you have a colimit just in $\mathcal A$.

Comment: @Alessandro Right and what about the other direction: If I have colimit in $\cal B $ is it colimit in $\cal A$ ?I think **not**: we may run out of $\cal A.$  Remember: I'm trying to make sense of the word **just** on the 5th line in the second snippet above.

Comment: You're right, the answer is no. Take a category $\mathcal B$ and the discrete subcategory $D(\mathcal B)$ made by taking the objects in $\mathcal B$ and no morphism, except for the identity morphisms. A colimit of the empty diagram $\emptyset\rightarrow\mathcal B$ is an initial object, which is no longer initial in $D(\mathcal B)$ (if $\mathcal B$ has more than two objects of course). Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the topic of the paper, so I can't really tell the meaning of the line you're asking about, sorry

Comment: @Alessandro How have you chosen $\cal B$ ?Just in the way that it has initial object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **flat object** in a variety $\mathcal{V}$ is a colimit in $\mathcal{V}$ of some small filtered diagram of finitely presentable projective objects in $\mathcal{V}$.
Note that every object in $\mathcal{V}$ is a colimit in $\mathcal{V}$ of some small filtered diagram of finitely presentable objects in $\mathcal{V}$ – the requirement of projectivity is doing all the work in this definition.
Every finitely presentable projective object is flat.
(All of this will make more sense if you think about the concrete example of the category of $R$-modules for some ring $R$.)

It is the case that if $\mathcal{K}$ is a full subcategory of $\mathcal{L}$ and you have a cocone in $\mathcal{K}$ that is a colimit cocone in $\mathcal{L}$, then it is also a colimit cocone in $\mathcal{K}$.
The converse is false, i.e. the inclusion $\mathcal{K} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{L}$ may fail to preserve colimits.
This is why it is important to specify not just whether a colimit is in the subcategory or not, but also whether their universal property is with respect to the subcategory or the ambient category.